# How to specify Gemfile so that it won't install a specific version of a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile, gemfile.lock

I'm new to ruby, and I'm trying to specify a specific version number to `rack`. I want `1.4.5` installed and `1.5.2` removed, and I did 
`gem uninstall rack --version 1.5.2`, 
and specified the version number of `rack` to `1.4.5` in file `Gemfile.lock`.

But after I got up this morning I found that `rack 1.5.2` was automatically installed back again, and the version of `rack` in `Gemfile.lock` was reset to `1.5.2`. How can I specify a configuration so the machine doesn't automatically do the things above?

Comment: You should use `Gemfile`, not `Gemfile.lock` for this purpose. You should never edit `Gemfile.lock` by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dont edit the `Gemfile.lock`, write this in the `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rack', '1.4.5'
```

If you have some warning or error message, type `bundle update rack`

Notice: Basically `Gemfile.lock` is the result of the `Gemfile` bundle